# Solving for intersection of line and a vector function.

Tags: linear-algebra, problem-solving, numerical-linear-algebra

How would one approach a problem of finding intersection points between a line $\vec l = \vec S + d \vec t$ and vector of the form $$\vec v = \begin{pmatrix}
x
\\ y
\\f(x, y)
\end{pmatrix}$$

I am mainly looking for fast numerical methods. If anyone would take the time to explain through example of $f(x, y) = sin(x) + sin(y) $

If there is a more general form to solve intersections between the line and vectors of form $\vec v'= \begin{pmatrix}
f_1(t)
\\ f_2(t)
\\f_3(t)
\end{pmatrix}$ then I would love to know that as well. To be exact I am looking for the first intersection (intersection with the lowest distance d in direction $\vec t$) Hope the question is not too vague. If it is please tell me about the constraints needed. Any reference or keyword helps. Thank you.

EDIT:

I am thinking that we can write $\vec l$ as a combination of its parts and then look at it as set of equations. Meaning: $$\vec l = \begin{pmatrix} \vec S_x + d \vec t_x \\ \vec S_y + d \vec t_y \\ \vec S_z + d \vec t_z\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow \vec l = \vec v \rightarrow  \begin{matrix} \vec S_x + d \vec t_x = x \\ \vec S_y + d \vec t_y = y \\  \vec S_z + d \vec t_z = f(x, y) \end{matrix}$$

Comment: First question: what is $\vec S$ vs. $S$? And do you want $d$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ such that $\vec v = \vec l$? (Or something else?)  In general, such a $\vec v$ is a curve parametrized by $x$ and $y$.  It is possible that your line and your curve do not intersect.  (For example, if $\vec v$ parametrizes a line parallel to $\vec l$).  Furthermore, $\vec v'$ is not necessarily more general than $\vec v$, since it is only parametrized by one variable, $t$.

Comment: Hopefully erased the confusion with $S$ and $\vec S$. They were meant to be components of $\vec S$. I wish to find d given line $\vec l$ and curve $\vec v$ defined above as a function of one or two variables in Cartesian room. It is possible, that they do not have an intersection point in case I would like to know that there exists no solution if possible. Furthermore it is possible to restrict the d to be non-negative if it is any help.